# Route parameter not passed from current page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a mix of (mostly) razor pages and controllers in a .NET Core 3.1 web app. I am trying to create a URL to a controller using URL.Action and everything works except it does not pass the parameters from the current page to the controller. My Startup.cs:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```

And in the controller itself:

```
[Area("Sales")]
[Route("Sales/Customers/Perks/[action]")]
public class PerksController : Controller
{
        [HttpGet("{cusno:decimal}")]
        public IActionResult Create(decimal cusno)
        {
        // Code here
        }
}
```

The page I'm calling from is a razor page with the following page directive:

```
@page "{cusno:decimal}/{branch}"
```

and trying to create a url on the page like this:

```
Url.Action("Create", "Perks", new { Area = "Sales" })
```

It will correctly create the URL with the routing I have setup if I make the cusno parameter optional in the controller action, but not if it's mandatory. It does not want to pass the parameter from the current page for some reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["cusno"]` to get cusno value from current url.Here is a demo:

TestAction.cshtml(In the page url is `https://localhost:xxx/Test/TestAction/{cusno}/{branch}`):

```
@page "{cusno:decimal}/{branch}"
<a href="/Sales/Customers/Perks/Create/@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["cusno"]">link</a>
```

PerksController:

```
[Area("Sales")]
    [Route("Sales/Customers/Perks/[action]")]
    public class PerksController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("{cusno:decimal}")]
        public IActionResult Create(decimal cusno)
        {
            // Code here
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: This works, but man is it ugly. I had this working in .NET core 2.1 without having to pass the parameters like this. Any ideas on what may have changed?

Comment: You mean you don't need to pass `cusno`?What is your current page url?My sample in the answer with href can be used no matter what the current url is.

Comment: I'm in the process of migrating from 2.1 to 3.1. The page I'm calling from is: /Sales/Customers/Branches/Details/100/01. And I used Url.Action("Create", "Perks", new { Area = "Sales" }). In 2.1, I didn't have to explicitly include the route parameters. In 3.1, it looks like I have to. Your answer works, as I updated the route values like this: new { Area = "Sales", cusno = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["cusno"] }.

Comment: I'm afraid not.I test and find the parameters will lose.So you need to find it in route and add it.

Comment: Okay, it looks like this is by design: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12794. Ambient route values from the current context are not propagated when you're generating a link to a different action in 2.2+. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Url.Action("Create", "Perks", new RouteValueDictionary(new { cusno = id }));
```

OR can also pass this way

```
Url.Action("Create", "Perks", new { cusno = id });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work: The name 'id' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: yeah, that was just example, you need to pass whatever variable you are using